# Error en el dato: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Tags: python, tweepy, etl

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from config import *
import json


try:
    auth = OAuthHandler(api_key,api_key_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
except BaseException as e:
    print("Error", e)


#tarjetasubeok
lst_hashtags = ['covid']

class TweetListener(Stream): 
   
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.full_text)
        
    def on_error(self,status):
         if status == 420:
            print("rate limit active")
            return False
        
    def on_data(self, tweetsData):  
        try:
            with open('tweets.json', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                f.write(tweetsData)
                #print(data)
                f.close
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('Error en el dato: %s' %str(e))
        return True
    
twitterStream = TweetListener(api_key,api_key_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)  
twitterStream.filter(track=lst_hashtags)
```

Comment: f.write(tweetsData.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.